# Email template error

Tags: templating, emails, csrf, error-templates

In the logs, I have this error:

> 2021-02-01 18:00:04 [-][-][-][error][craft\commerce\services\Emails::sendEmail] Email template parse error for email “Order Submitted”. Order: “123456”. Template error: “An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Getting unknown property: craft\console\Request::csrfParam").” /home/project/templates/shop/_includes/order-review.twig:48

The code that it points to is this:

```html
<form method="post">
     {{ csrfInput() }}
     {{ actionInput('commerce/cart/update-cart') }}
     {{ redirectInput('/shop/checkout/payment') }}
     <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text"name="couponCode" value="{{ cart.couponCode }}" placeholder="{{ "Coupon Code"|t }}">
          <div class="input-group-append">
               <button type="submit" class="btn btn-purple">Update Cart</button>
          </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you have a bit more context on how you request the template?
It seems to be using the console Request, which doesn't have a csrfParam variable.
This variable is only available in the web Request.

Comment: @Joorren This is code for entering a coupon code on a checkout page. When a user enters a code, it updates the order and refreshes the page. There isn't a controller as the routing is done via the file structure of the templates.

Comment: Can you edit the question and share the full stack trace leading up to the error?

Comment: @BradBell I edited the question

Comment: Is there more to the stack trace? That looks like the first line of it.

Comment: @BradBell There isn't any more in queue.log. Would I be able to find it somewhere else?